# how to decrease 5 month from the today date in codeigniter php

Tags: php

i have today date like `2013-03-09 02:12:36` i want to get the output like `2012-10-09 02:12:36` (5 month ago time)

I am getting today with code
             
              `$datestring = "%Y-%m-%d: %d:%h:%i";
              $time = time(); 
              $today=mdate($datestring, $time);//gives me`2013-03-09 02:12:36``

What i want is 
              `$sixmonth= $today  - 6 month//how to get this output`

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function named `strtotime()`, this will do what you want. You should read up about how the function works [here](http://www.php.net/strtotime). You should also look into the `date()` function to format your dates and times, you can do that so [here](http://www.php.net/date).

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-6 months"));
```

Example output:

```
root@upstairslinux:~# php 6months.php
2012-09-09 12:20:23

root@upstairslinux:~#
```